# While loop gets same record multiple times

Tags: php, while-loop

I've spent HOURS on this and I can't figure it out.  My while loop below returns the same record (Sub-Total:) three times.  Please see the image below for my table structure.  Also, this is in an OsCommerce installation, so the "tep_....." functions are an OsCommerce thing.  I don't believe they're the problem though because I've tried a few other non-OsCommerce solutions here.

```
$ot_query = tep_db_query("select * from " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . " where orders_id = '" . (int) $order_id . "'");
if (tep_db_num_rows($ot_query)) {
    while ($ot = tep_db_fetch_array($ot_query)) {
        $order_total_sql = tep_db_query("select * from " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . " where orders_id = '" . (int) $order_id . "'");
        $order_total_result = tep_db_fetch_array($order_total_sql);
        $email_order .= strip_tags($order_total_result['title']) . ' ' . strip_tags($order_total_result['text']) . "\n";
    }
}
```

Table Structure...

```
orders_total_id   |   orders_id   |   title   |   text   |   value   |   class   |   sort_order
```

There are three different rows that have the same orders_id, but different orders_total_id's and of course the other data is different as well.

--- UPDATE ---

Adding

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($ot, 1)."</pre>\n";
```

under the **while ($ot = tep_db_fetch_array($ot_query)) {** produced the following...

```
Array
(
    [orders_total_id] => 4149
    [orders_id] => 1280
    [title] => Sub-Total:
    [text] => $49.99
    [value] => 49.9900
    [class] => ot_subtotal
    [sort_order] => 1
)
Array
(
    [orders_total_id] => 4150
    [orders_id] => 1280
    [title] => Gift Certificates (-) :
    [text] => $37.00
    [value] => 37.0000
    [class] => ot_gv
    [sort_order] => 3
)
Array
(
    [orders_total_id] => 4151
    [orders_id] => 1280
    [title] => Total:
    [text] => $12.99
    [value] => 12.9900
    [class] => ot_total
    [sort_order] => 12
)
```

Comment: please add a tag indicating what language this is for

Comment: What is with people and their indenting? Is it that hard?

Comment: Have you actually checked your database to ensure that the record isn't there three times? (And also, is the ID guaranteed to be unique?)

Comment: @ arxanas: There are three records with the same "orders_id", but they contain different data.  The "orders_total_id" is guaranteed to be unique since it auto increments on each entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is on the line after your `while()` -- the one that sets `$order_total_sql`.  You're doing a SELECT using just one record -- and it's NOT the one that you've stored in `$ot` from the previous SELECT.  You're basing your output on the wrong data.

So the answer is ... use `$ot` instead of making a second SELECT.

```
$ot_query = tep_db_query("select * from " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . " where orders_id = '" . (int) $order_id . "'");
if (tep_db_num_rows($ot_query)) {
    while ($ot = tep_db_fetch_array($ot_query)) {
        $email_order .= strip_tags($ot['title']) . ' ' . strip_tags($ot['text']) . "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not changing $order_id inside the main loop, so your inner query is never changing - you always fetch the same record(s) each time. Shouldn't you have something like...

```
while ($ot = tep_db_fetch_array($ot_query)) {
   $order_id = $od['order_id'];
   $order_total_sql = etc...
   etc...
}
```

of course, that doesn't answer why you're running the same query twice... You're selecting the exact same construct 'outside' as you are 'indside'...

Comment: I tried what you had (and corrected a couple typos) and it doesn't work.  It's still the same three rows.  The rows are actually the last of the three though (the ones with the lowest "orders_total_id").

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting records that are have same `orders_id`:

```
$ot_query = tep_db_query("select * from " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . " where orders_id = '" . (int) $order_id . "'");
```

As I can see, `orders_id` is ID of the order and `orders_total_id` is id of sub-total record. In your example you have:

```
Sub-Total: $49.99
Gift Certificates (-) : $37.00
```

49.99 - 37.00 = 12.99, so:

```
Total: $12.99
```